# Jtable not showing what is in the database (MySQL Query browser is used) in Java

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I am working on something which is getting data from database and transfer it to a JTable in Java. My problem is, the data gathered is not showing in my JTable. I tried debugging it by printing the query in Java, it prints but it does not show any data in JTable. Please help me, thanks in advance. TT_TT

Here is my UI code

```
    /*
 * Programmer       : Inodeo, Claire Fatima R.
 * Date Developed   : April 20, 2015 
 * Company          : 
 * Purpose          : To gather data from database and display it 
 *                    to JTable. A desktop application which requires Java to be installed
 *                    in PC for it to run. For Java installer visit www.oracle.com and download the
 *                    latest version of Java. 
 * */               
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.swing.*;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class UserInterface extends JPanel
{



    private JButton  srch_btn;
    table_data obj;

    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

    //JLabel
    private JLabel   date_lbl;
    private JLabel   frm_lbl;
    private JLabel   to_lbl;
    private JLabel   pl_lbl;
    private JLabel   where_lbl;

    //SQL
    Connection con=null;
    Statement stmt = null;  

    //ComboBox
    private JComboBox<String> frm_drp;
    private JComboBox<String> to_drp;
    private JComboBox<String> brngy_drp;

    public static String names[] = {"Negros", "Panay","Leyte"};
    public static JComboBox<String> city_drp;

    //******CONSTRUCTOR*********************

    public UserInterface()
    {
        //construct components
        obj         = new table_data    ();
        srch_btn    = new JButton       ("Search");
        date_lbl    = new JLabel        ("DATE:");
        frm_lbl     = new JLabel        ("From             :");
        to_lbl      = new JLabel        ("To                  :");
        frm_drp     = new JComboBox<>   ();
        to_drp      = new JComboBox<>   ();
        pl_lbl      = new JLabel        ("PLACE");
        where_lbl   = new JLabel        ("Where           :");
        city_drp    = new JComboBox<>   (names); 
        brngy_drp   = new JComboBox<>   ();

        //adjust size and set layout
        setPreferredSize (new Dimension (900, 400));
        setLayout (null); 
        //*****************************SQL GOES HERE************************************
        //==================================================================================
        //=========================Combox for places==========================================
        //==================================================================================
        city_drp.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String chosenName =  (String) city_drp.getSelectedItem();
                //removes all the unecessary things in comboBox
                //prevents overlapping informations
                brngy_drp.removeAllItems();
                to_drp.removeAllItems();
                frm_drp.removeAllItems();

                if(chosenName.equals("Panay"))
                {

                    try {
                        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://:3306/ngcp_table","root","root");
                        stmt = con.createStatement();
                        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT Panay_Place, Panay_Date FROM ngcp_table.panay;");



                        while(rs.next())
                         {

                            brngy_drp.addItem   (rs.getString("Panay_Place"));    
                            frm_drp.addItem     (rs.getString("Panay_Date"));
                            to_drp.addItem      (rs.getString("Panay_Date"));  

                         }
                         rs.close();
                         stmt.close();
                         con.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }else if(chosenName.equals("Negros"))
                {

                    try {
                        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://:3306/ngcp_table","root","root");
                        stmt = con.createStatement();
                        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT Negros_Place, Negros_Date FROM ngcp_table.negros;");

                        while(rs.next())
                         {

                                    brngy_drp.addItem   (rs.getString("Negros_Place")); 
                                    frm_drp.addItem (rs.getString("Negros_Date"));
                                    to_drp.addItem  (rs.getString("Negros_Date"));

                         }
                         rs.close();
                         stmt.close();
                         con.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }else if(chosenName.equals("Leyte"))
                {

                    try {
                        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://:3306/ngcp_table","root","root");
                        stmt = con.createStatement();
                        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT Leyte_Place, Leyte_Date FROM ngcp_table.leyte;");

                        while(rs.next())
                         {
                                     brngy_drp.addItem  (rs.getString("Leyte_Place"));
                                     frm_drp.addItem    (rs.getString("Leyte_Date"));
                                     to_drp.addItem     (rs.getString("Leyte_Date"));


                         }
                         rs.close();
                         stmt.close();
                         con.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        });
        //***************************FOR TABLE***********************
        //====================SEARCH BUTTON==========================
        srch_btn.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
            @Override                   
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //loads the information from the database to the JTABLE


                scrollPane = obj.table((frm_drp.getSelectedIndex()+1),(to_drp.getSelectedIndex()+1),(brngy_drp.getSelectedIndex()+1)); //JScrollPane table(char sample_Place, char sample_Date, int KW,int KV)

                System.out.println("this is " +frm_drp.getSelectedItem());
                System.out.println("this is " +to_drp.getSelectedItem());
                System.out.println("this is " +brngy_drp.getSelectedItem()); 

                if (scrollPane == null) {
                        scrollPane.setSize(100, 300); //END OF TABLE CODES
                        System.out.println("no");

                    } else {
                        add(scrollPane);
                        System.out.println("yes");
                    }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }


        });//*********************END OF SEARCH BUTTON CODE******************

        //=============================================================================
        //===========COMPONENTS WILL BE ADDED HERE AND SIZE WILL BE SET================
        //=============================================================================

        //add components
        add (srch_btn);
        add (date_lbl);
        add (frm_lbl);
        add (to_lbl);
        add (frm_drp);
        add (to_drp);
        add (pl_lbl);
        add (where_lbl);
        add (city_drp);
        add (brngy_drp);
        scrollPane = obj.table((frm_drp.getSelectedIndex()+1),(to_drp.getSelectedIndex()+1),(brngy_drp.getSelectedIndex()+1));
        add (scrollPane);

        //*******set component bounds (only needed by Absolute Positioning)***********
        srch_btn.setBounds (140, 240, 105, 25);
        date_lbl.setBounds (25, 40, 100, 25);
        frm_lbl.setBounds (45, 70, 100, 25);
        to_lbl.setBounds (45, 110, 100, 25);
        frm_drp.setBounds (100, 70, 150, 25);
        to_drp.setBounds (100, 105, 150, 25);
        pl_lbl.setBounds (25, 140, 100, 25);
        where_lbl.setBounds (40, 170, 100, 25);
        city_drp.setBounds (100, 170, 150, 25);
        brngy_drp.setBounds (100, 200, 150, 25);

    }

    //===================================================================================
    //=============================MAIN PROGRAM GOES HERE================================
    //===================================================================================
     public static void main (String[] args) 
     {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame ("NGCP DATA SYSTEM");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().add (new UserInterface());
            frame.pack();
            frame.add(new JScrollPane());
            frame.setVisible (true);
      }
}
```

and here is my Table code

```
    //for SQL
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
//javaSwing
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class table_data extends JFrame 
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JTable table_Panel;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private DefaultTableModel dtm;
    Connection con=null;
    Statement stmt = null;  

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public JScrollPane table(int Date,int Date2, int place)
    {
        String columnLabel[] = {"Date","KW","KV"};

        dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
        dtm.addColumn(columnLabel[0]);
        dtm.addColumn(columnLabel[1]);
        dtm.addColumn(columnLabel[2]);

        //creates a static table

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://:3306/ngcp_table","root","root");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery
                    (
                                    "SELECT * FROM ngcp_table.negros "
                                    + "WHERE Negros_Place = '"+place+"'AND Negros_Date BETWEEN '" + Date + "' AND '" + Date2 + "'"


                    );
            System.out.println("Hellowsss");

            while(rs.next())
            {                   
                    dtm.addRow(new Object[]
                            { 

                                rs.getString("Negros_Date"), rs.getString("KW"), rs.getString("KV")                         
                            }
                    );
                    System.out.println("YEAH VAERY NICE");
            }

             rs.close();
             stmt.close();
             con.close();

        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        table_Panel = new JTable(dtm);


        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table_Panel);
        scrollPane.setVisible(true);
        scrollPane.setBounds(280, 15, 600, 380); //setbounds(x,y,width,lenth);


        return scrollPane;

    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly isn't working?  BTW is the url for mysql correct?  Host seems to be missing?

Comment: Have you tried calling `revalidate` and `repaint` AFTER `add(scrollPane);`?  Why does `table_data` extend from `JFrame` when you don't actually use any of the functionality of `JFrame`?  I might also add, this seems like a lot of running around in circles for little gain.  You only need the `TableModel`, you could leave the `JTable` on the screen and simply replace the model

Comment: You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Comment: You might consider also using `PreparedStatement`s, which will make your code safer to execute and easier to debug and less likely to destroy your database. [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: Thank you all for your quick response.. I am still learning Java, and sorry for my coding style.. I'm going to research about the functionality of each JSwing.. 
@ScaryWombat: my table does not show the data gathered in sql. 
Thank you very much. :) I appreciate all your help. :))